# Better way of checking query string parmeter in Django

Tags: python, django

I have quite some integer query string params that  I convert this way. Is there built in better way in python to handle this ?

```
current_page = request.GET.get('page')
if current_page is not None and current_page.isnumeric():
    current_page  = int(current_page )
else 
    current_page = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way might be to just try to convert it, and use `1` if it fails:

```
try:
    current_page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
except ValueError:
    current_page = 1
```

Comment: why dont just `current_page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))` ? because of non numeric?

Comment: @itzMEonTV: because the page can contain `'foo'`. In fact Django's `MultipleObjectMixin` allows the page to contain `'last'`, and then sets it to the last page for example.